# Trying to calculate checksum but end up stuck in infinite loop - please explain?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to calculate the checksum from a given card number. I know there's plenty of ready made better performing algorithms out there. What I'd like to know is why do I get stuck in an infinite loop I just don't get it.

'numbers' is a list of chars from a String e.g ("4000002345326738")

```
def get_checksum(numbers):
sum_ = 0
for n in numbers:
    x = int(n)
    sum_ += x
found = False
checksum = 0
while not found:
    if sum_ % 10 == 0:
        return checksum
    else:
        checksum += 1
        sum_ += checksum
```

Comment: You are adding checksum to sum_ but checksum keeps being incremented.

Comment: You only need to return sum_ % 10

Comment: I understand however the while loop is independent of the checksum variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us see, each iteration checksum increases by one, and sum_ increases by checksum. This means that at iteration number n, your sum_ is equal to

sum_ = sum_initial + 1 + 2 + ... + n = sum_initial + n*(n+1)/2

You believe that at some point sum_ will be divisible by 10. This is not true. The remainder of n(n+1)/2 modulo 10 only depends on n % 20, so it easy to see that possible values of n(n+1)/2 % 10 are:

0, 1, 3, 6, 5, 8

So, if the initial sum_ is 1, 3, 6, or 8 modulo 10, the sum_ will never be divisible by 2, and you get stuck in an infinite cycle.

BTW, since `found` variable is not used anywhere, you could just write
`while True:`

Comment: Look at the if statement. There is a return in there. Fix your answer.

Comment: Doesn't "return checksum" automatically stop the loop since we are leaving the function?

Comment: Super Malaysia! You nailed it.